# strange behavior when passing variadic arguments

Tags: c++, c, variadic-functions

I thougt, `printf` would take also a `va_list`
but when i do so, `printf` doesn't do what I want `printf` to do:

```
void Log(int loglevel, char* string, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, string);

    switch (type)
    {
        case LOGLEVEL_FATAL:
            printf("FATAL: ");
            break;

        case LOGLEVEL_ERROR:
            printf("ERROR: ");
            break;

        case LOGLEVEL_WARNING:
            printf("WARNING: ");
            break;

        case LOGLEVEL_INFO:
            printf("INFO: ");
            break;
    }

    printf(string, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

When i now call:

```
Log(LOGLEVEL_INFO, "testvariable = %f", 16.0);
```

the output is:

```
INFO: testvariable = 0.000000
```

But why?
What's my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final `printf()` call should be to [`vprintf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vprintf/) ("v" for varargs).

Comment: but why dont i get an error if i pass an `va_list` to `printf()`?

Comment: @Schnizel1337: Because `printf()` isn't typesafe. In your case it expects a `double` and gets a `va_list`. However, this isn't checked.

Comment: @Schnizel1337 `printf()` accepts anything and interprets its arguments **only** according to the format specifiers. The `va_list` is a single argument. Have you seen a format specifier for a `va_list`?

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 you can do this (in a header file):

```
template<typename... Args>
void Log(int loglevel, char* string, Args&&... args)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case LOGLEVEL_FATAL:
            printf("FATAL: ");
            break;

        case LOGLEVEL_ERROR:
            printf("ERROR: ");
            break;

        case LOGLEVEL_WARNING:
            printf("WARNING: ");
            break;

        case LOGLEVEL_INFO:
            printf("INFO: ");
            break;
    }

    printf(string, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

which would also, in theory, let you parse `string` and determine if the `args` are in fact the right ones, rather than blindly crashing.